# CSS flexbox breaking behaviour

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to realize **a 'reponsive' box** (having a fix width) containing **a logo** (having a fix width) and **an infobar** (taking the rest width of the main box). The width of the infobar is therefor calced with `calc()` As the infobar would be useless if getting to small it also contains a `min-width`.

This works well until the screen width gets so small that the flexbox has to break into two rows. Now there are two problems in my design, i would like to solve:

1) I want the logo in wrap-row 1 to be centered horizontally

2) I want the infobar taking the whole width of wrap-row 2

*(In my solution the logo sticks on the left of the first wrap-row and the infobar in the second wrap-row lacks the size of the logo, which I subtracted.)*

**Is there a solution using flexboxes?**

Code (HTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="test.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box wrap" align="center">
<div class="logo">logo</div>
<div class="infobar">infobar</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code (test.css):

```
div.wrap{margin:0 auto;display:-webkit-box;display:-moz-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:-webkit-flex;-webkit-flex-wrap:wrap;display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap}
div.box{min-height:100px;max-width:1200px}
div.logo{width:200px;min-height:128px;margin-bottom:10px;margin-right:10px;background-color:#456789}
div.infobar{width:calc(99% - 215px);min-width:320px;min-height:128px;text-align:left;padding-left:3px;padding-top:3px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:#ABCDEF}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable auto growing to your infobox, so it fills the remaining space, and centering your whole content.

```
div.infobar {
  flex-grow: 1; /* Fill the remaining space */
}

div.wrap {
  justify-content: center; /* Center whole content */
}
```

Your whole code could look like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/yavv5Ldy/).